# If $x=[a_0,a_1,\dots]$ show that $\mu$-almost every $x \in (0,1/N]$ is infinitely recurrent

Tags: number-theory, measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, continued-fractions

> Let $G$ be the Gauss map,
>   $$G(x)= \begin{cases}
> 0 & \text{if} \ x=0 \\ 
>  \{\frac{1}{x} \}=\frac{1}{x} \ \mathrm{mod} \ 1 & \text{if $0<x\leq 1$}\end{cases}$$
>
> and $\mu$ be the Gauss measure given by integrating the density $\frac{1}{\ln 2}\left(\frac{1}{1+x}\right)$.
>
> Let $N >0$ be a given positive integer. Show that for $\mu$-almost every $x \in (0,\frac{1}{N}]$ there are infinitely many entries $a_i$ in the continued fraction expansion of $x=[a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n,\dots]$ such that $a_i \geq N$.

I believe this can be solved by applying the strong form of the Poincaré recurrence theorem. As $a_n = \left[\frac{1}{G^n(x)}\right]$ if $a_i \geq N$ then $\frac{1}{N+1} \leq G^n(x)\leq \frac{1}{N}$.

We know that $\mu((0,\frac{1}{N}])>0$ (easily shown). Therefore $\mu$-almost every $x \in B=\left(0\,\frac{1}{N}\right]$ is infinitely recurrent to $B$.

> Prove the conclusion of the previous part holds for $\mu$-almost every $x \in [0,1]$.

How does this work. I think it would be the same proof, but this does not feel right (and seems to easy).

These are the versions of the Poincaré recurrence that I know.

[image]
[image]

and this may be useful

[image]

Also you may assume that $G$ is ergodic wrt $\mu$.

Comment: The Gauss map is ergodic with respect to the Gauss measure (books on ergodic theory that discuss the Gauss map should show this), so use the refinement of the Poincare recurrence theorem for ergodic transformations: if $(X,T,\mu)$ is ergodic and $\mu(X) < \infty$ then for any measurable subset $B \subset X$ with positive measure $\mu$-almost all points of $X$ will have their $T$-orbit intersect $B$ infinitely often.

Comment: I am not familiar with this refinement. Could you point me to where it is or how it works.

Comment: In the notation of my previous comment let $f = \chi_B$, characteristic function of $B$. This is in $L^1(X,\mu)$, and for any $x \in X$ the proportion of terms in $x,T(x),\dots,T^{n-1}(x)$ that lie in $B$ is $(1/n)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(T^k(x))$. Since $T$ is ergodic, one of the basic consequences of Birkhoff's ergodic theorem is that for $\mu$-almost all $x$ the average converges as $n \rightarrow \infty$ to $(1/\mu(X))\int_X f\,d\mu = \mu(B)/\mu(X)$. This limit is positive, so for $\mu$-almost all $x$ we have $f(T^k(x)) \not= 0$ for infinitely many $k$, so $T^k(x) \in B$ inf. often.

Comment: @KCd I have edited my question to show what I do know.  Im also not entirely sure what you mean with your last comment. Moreover I believe your comments are closer to an answer than a comment.

Comment: Your question is to show, for the example of the Gauss map on $[0,1]$, that almost all $x \in [0,1]$ have infinitely many continued fraction entries greater than $N$, which is equivalent (as you say) to showing almost all $x$ have their Gauss orbit meet $(0,1/N)$ infinitely often. My previous comment showed this follows from the ergodic theorem: in any ergodic dynamical system of finite measure, almost all elements have their orbit meet a predetermined subset of positive measure infinitely often (this uses a function $f$ whose only values are 0 and 1). What are you not sure about from this?

Comment: Im sure youre correct, its just hard to see how the ergodic refinement can be obtained from my course. I feel that there is probably an easier way to explain this using mathematics I am more comfortable with.

Comment: I cannot see how your second comment works. I cannot understand the conclusion of the comment in the last sentence. I do not see how or why the Birkhoff ergodic theorem was applied.

Comment: I don't know what your "course" is about. You write at the end of the question that you're willing to assume the Gauss map is ergodic, so I think it's safe to assume you know what that term means. Have you seen the ergodic theorem in your course, and if so what examples have you seen it used for (e.g., normal numbers in $[0,1]$)?

Comment: http://www.maths.bris.ac.uk/~maxcu/DSET/DynSysErgThPartIII_14-15.pdf

Comment: On the very first page of those notes it is explained how frequency counts of an orbit meeting a subset can be written as an average of a characteristic function. The bottom of page 40 of the notes (p. 41 of the pdf file) connects the limiting behavior of this frequency to the ergodic theorem in *exactly* the way I was doing it above; did you not get to that part of the notes yet? Starting on the bottom of page 43 of the notes (p. 44 of the pdf file) is the application of ergodic theory to statistics of continued fraction entries (how often $a_n = k$). Reread those notes, I guess.

Comment: Sadly I have read these notes many times. Ill reread everything now again.

Comment: @KCd Ok I can understand your ergodic refinement now, however I still cant fully see how the theorem could be "seen" from my notes. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the question being asked can be settled using ergodicity of the Gauss map and the ergodic theorem, as I explained in comments to the question, it can also be explained using only the ergodicity alone (which is itself a nontrivial feature of the Gauss map, so it's not like we're getting something for free). I'll state the result in a general context, as an ergodic refinement of the Poincare recurrence theorem.

Theorem: If $(X,\mu,T)$ is an ergodic dynamical system with $0 < \mu(X) < \infty$, then for each measurable subset $A \subset X$ with $\mu(A) > 0$, $\mu$-almost all $x \in X$ have $T^n(x) \in A$ for infinitely many $n$.

The distinction from the Poincare recurrence theorem is that the conclusion is about $\mu$-almost all $x \in X$ rather than $\mu$-almost all $x \in A$.

Proof: For $m \geq 0$, let $X_m$ be the set of $x \in X$ such that $T^n(x) \in A$ for some $n \geq m$. In set-theoretic notation, $X_m = \bigcup_{n \geq m} T^{-n}(A)$.  This set is measurable and $\mu(X_m) > 0$ since 
$\mu(X_m) \geq \mu(T^{-m}(A)) = \mu(A) > 0$.

Check $T^{-1}(X_m) \subset X_m$ (that is, if $T(x) \in X_m$ then $x \in X_m$). Since $X_m$ and $T^{-1}(X_m)$ have equal $\mu$-measure, the complement $X_m  - T^{-1}(X_m)$ has measure $0$. Outside of $X_m  - T^{-1}(X_m)$, check that $\chi_{X_m}(x) = \chi_{X_m}(Tx)$ by looking separately at $x \in T^{-1}(X_m)$ (both sides are $1$) and at $x \in X - X_m$ (both sides are $0$). Therefore $\chi_{X_m}(x) = \chi_{X_m}(Tx)$ for $\mu$-*almost all* $x \in X$, so $\chi_{X_m} \colon X \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ is an almost invariant function on $(X,\mu,T)$. Therefore the set $\{x \in X : \chi_{X_m}(x) = 1\} = X_m$ is an almost invariant set, and when the dynamical system is ergodic its almost invariant sets have measure $0$ or full measure. As $\mu(X_m) > 0$, we must have $\mu(X_m) = \mu(X)$: $\mu$-almost all points of $X$ are in $X_m$, so the complement of $X_m$ has $\mu$-measure zero.

What is the complement of $X_m$? It's the $x \in X$ such that $T^n(x) \not\in A$ for all $n \geq m$. A countable union of measure $0$ sets has measure $0$, so $\mu$-almost all $x \in X$ are outside the complement of every $X_m$, meaning $\mu$-almost all $x \in X$ are in every $X_m$.  To say $x$ lies in every $X_m$ means $T^n(x) \in A$ for some $n \geq m$ no matter what $m$ is, and that's another way of saying $T^n(x) \in A$ for infinitely many $n$.  Thus $\mu$-almost all $x \in X$ have their $T$-orbit $\{x,T(x),T^2(x),\dots\}$ meet $A$ infinitely often provided $\mu(A) > 0$.