# Show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n} (a_i+1) \right)^{1/n} $ using Birkhoff Ergodic Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, limits, measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Show that for Lebesgue-almost every $x \in [0,1)$, the geometric mean

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n} (a_i+1) \right)^{1/n} $$

exists and has common value. What is this? (no proof required)

I think this has something to do with the Birkhoff ergodic Theorem

[image]

I tried $$\begin{align} \log \left( \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n} (a_i+1) \right)^{1/n} \right) &=  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \log\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n} (a_i+1) \right)^{1/n} \\
&= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log (a_i+1) \\ 
&= ....???
\end{align}$$

It was shown in the part before that if $x = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_i}{10^i}$ where $a_i \in \{0,1,\dots,9 \}$ that for Lebesgue-almost every $x \in [0,1)$ that

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i=\frac{9}{2} $$

but I cannot see how this can be used.

Comment: There is no $x$ in your limit. How are the $a_i$'s related to the $x$ of the statement?

Comment: Also, either $\prod_{i=1}^\infty (a_i+1)$ is a finite value or not. If it is a finite positive value, it doesn't vary with $n$, so the limit would be $1$. Did you mean $\prod_{i=1}^n$?

Comment: I assume the product goes to $n$, not $\infty$. As written, that limit exists if and only if the infinite product converges. In which case the limit is 0 or 1.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes i did. I have edited my question now.

Comment: @ClementC. See solution 11.4, starts page 136 of these notes. http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~cwalkden/ergodic-theory/ergodic_theory.pdf

Comment: Since the distribution of the digits is shift-invariant, assuming that such a limit exists for almost every number, it must be the geometric mean of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$, i.e. $4.5287\ldots$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Could you explain further please? Does your solution link to $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i=\frac{9}{2}$ (which would be the ideal answer?

Comment: @1234: yes, we have just the geometric mean of the digits plus one instead of the arithmetic mean of the digits. Same idea: for almost every number, the occurrences of different digits have balanced frequencies.

Comment: But theres a $\log$? I get the idea I just cant see this exactly.

Comment: This is exactly like Theorem 3.7.3 of your class notes http://www.maths.bris.ac.uk/~maxcu/DSET/DynSysErgThPartIII_14-15.pdf that you put in a comment to your other question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1088605/if-x-a-0-a-1-dots-show-that-mu-almost-every-x-in-0-1-n-is-infinitel, but using $\log(1+x)$ in place of a characteristic function. Have you ever *applied* the ergodic theorem to an example of a function $f$ that is not a characteristic function?

Comment: Yes in order to obtain $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i=\frac{9}{2}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $n$th term is $\exp(S_n(x)/n)$ where $$S_n(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^nX_k(x),\qquad X_k(x)=\log(1+a_k(x)).$$ With respect to the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1)$, the sequence $(a_k)$ is i.i.d. hence $(X_k)$ is i.i.d. and $S_n\to E(X_1)$ almost surely, by the strong law of large numbers for i.i.d. integrable sequences. Furthermore, $a_1$ is uniform on $\{0,1,\ldots,9\}$ hence $E(X_1)=\frac1{10}\sum\limits_{i=0}^9\log(1+i)=\frac1{10}\log(10!)$.
Thus, $\exp(S_n(x)/n)\to\ell$ for almost every $x$, where $$\ell=\exp(E(X_1))=(10!)^{1/10}\approx4.5287,$$ and in particular, $\ell\ne9/2$.

Nota: One may replace "the strong law of large numbers for i.i.d. integrable sequences" above by "Birkhoff ergodic theorem".